# Как не учитывать колонку при использовании функции datatables?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

Есть следующая функция таблицы datatables: https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/column-control.html . Как не учитывать две последних колонки таблицы при сжатии экрана? Нужно, чтобы они не уходили под плюс, а оставались отображенными, и чтобы при этом на других колонках это не отобразилось(они всё так же уходят под плюс)?

```
$("#table").dataTable({
                responsive: {
        details: {
            type: 'column'
        }
            },
            columnDefs: [ {
                className: 'control',
                orderable: false,
                targets:   0
            } ],
            order: [ 1, 'asc' ]
});
```

Возможно вопрос глупый, но я недавно начал учить js, а задача такая внезапно попалась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить к 2 столбцам специальный класс `all`:
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes#Special-classes